# React Test Renderer Act Function

Tags: reactjs, testing

I’ve gone through all the documentation I can find. What does the react test renderer act() function actually do? They give short justifications here and there, but I mean at a more technical level.

Ty!

https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrendereract

Answer (score 2):

[This document](https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md) is the best explanation I've found, although it still seems incomplete.

In short:

In synchronous use (i.e. the callback function you pass to `act()` does not return a Promise, and you don't await the results), `act(f)` runs `f`, then makes sure that any React state updates and effects started during `f` are finished before returning.

In asynchronous use (`f` returns a Promise, and then you await the results of `act(f)`), it... maybe also magically waits for any Promises created during `f`? It's not really clear. In a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/issues/6) filed on the above document, someone asked the author to clarify this, but they haven't responded.